# Самый хороший подарок — это(,) когда

Tags: пунктуация

Как правильно оформить предложение? Нужно тире перед *это*? А запятая?

> Самый хороший подарок — это(,) когда ты с душой что-то даришь.

Comment: Самый хороший подарок это, когда ты с душой что-то даришь.

Comment: Только запятой здесь и не хватало))  Прочитайте, что вы написали) (На месте запятой сделайте паузу.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Тире нужно, оно соединяет подлежащее и сказуемое, а вот запятую ни в коем случае ставить нельзя:

***Самый хороший подарок — это когда ты с душой что-то даришь***.

В данном случае, считая *когда ты с душой что-то даришь* придаточным, вы **лишаете подлежащие сказуемого**. Почему? Потому что придаточные можно всегда убрать без потери структуры:

***Самый хороших подарок — это***.

И на этом всë? Серьезно? Что *это*? Какой самый хороший подарок? Ничего непонятно, да и некорректно тоже. Тире разделяет подлежащее и сказуемое, а вы, считая его придаточным, убрали. Тогда зачем вообще стоит тире, если подлежащее есть, а сказуемого нет?

Плюс ко всему все эти слова входят в состав сказуемого, поэтому никаких запятых ставить нельзя.

Comment: Максим, как вы сами оцениваете ваш (принятый!) ответ? Предикативная основа:  Подарок - это. Вы именно это хотели сказать?

Comment: А где же объяснение: почему эти слова входят в состав сказуемого, на каких правах? Объяснение длинное, но непонятное. Это диалог? А с кем?  Поймите меня правильно: я хочу, чтобы ваши ответы были очень хорошими (краткими и точными). Мне теперь нравятся такие. В ответе должна быть обозначена композиция: вот ответ, вот пояснение, а вот дополнительные материалы (словари, примеры и т.д.).  Мало у кого я вижу такую структуру:  слов много, а смысл приходится разыскивать)

Comment: @Sharon Хорошо, учту ваше замечание.

Comment: Спасибо! Надеюсь на вашу  успешную работу)

Answer (score 2):

*Самый хороший подарок — это **когда ты с душой что-то даришь**.*

***Подарок*** — подлежащее, ***это*** — связка, придаточное предложение в позиции **сказуемого.**

Тире ставится по обычным  правилам. Стиль **разговорный,** но такие предложения в литературе встречаются часто.

**Пример:**

— Знаете, господа, по-моему, самое сильное впечатление — *это когда* ищешь что-то, долго-долго, может, всю жизнь, и уже почти смиришься, что не нашел и никогда не найдешь — и вдруг вот оно...