# Как обнаружить подлежащее и сказуемое? (Предложение из вопроса Леопольда.)

Tags: синтаксис, сказуемые, подлежащее, грамматическая-основа

Помните, Леопольд задавал вопрос про запятую *это(,) когда*? Так вот, у меня возник вопрос по этому поводу: а где подлежащее, где — сказуемое?

> Самый хороший подарок — это когда ты с душой что-то даришь.

Это, собственно, и есть его центральное предложение в вопросе. Не особо понятно, входит ли определение *самый хороший* (превосходная степень сравнения) в состав подлежащего; а со сказуемым вообще непонятно. Совы, подскажите, как правильно?

Comment: Максим, все совы улетели. Осень...))

Comment: Кстати:  https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/475907/Самый-хороший-подарок-это-когда

Comment: @Sharon Так оттуда я и взял. А под _совами_ вы имели в виду то, что я, как Лео, продолжаю это слово использовать? Так я далеко не полностью под него подстраиваюсь (теперь-то) ))

Comment: Да я так, с юмором. Множества сов действительно почему-то не видно...))    А адресок для справок.

Comment: @Sharon Хорошо. А вы знаете ответ на мой вопрос? Думаю, может, ответите. )

Comment: Возможно, но я сейчас ухожу... Может, позже, если ответов не будет)

Comment: @Sharon Хорошо.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***Самый хороший подарок** — это когда ты с душой что-то даришь.*

**ПОДЛЕЖАЩЕЕ**

Я думаю, что в данном предложении можно считать подлежащим  ***"самый хороший подарок".***

Это **контекстуально несвободное** словосочетание. В другом контесте оно будет свободным.

**ПОДАРОК,** -рка; м. 1. То, что дарят, что подарено. Денежный п. Свадебный п. Преподнести книгу в п.

**СКАЗУЕМОЕ**

Про сказуемое я уже ответила раньше: **это придаточное предложение в позиции сказуемого.**

[https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/475907/Самый-хороший-подарок-это-когда](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/475907/%D0%A1%D0%B0%D0%BC%D1%8B%D0%B9-%D1%85%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%88%D0%B8%D0%B9-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BA-%D1%8D%D1%82%D0%BE-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%B4%D0%B0)

Что еще добавить? Могу добавить материал **о контаминации** https://proza.ru/2023/03/08/612

Иногда **сложная конструкция** (предложение, оборот речи) выступает в качестве  **структурного элемента** (например, одного слова) при построении **другой конструкции.** Это явление можно назвать **КОНТАМИНАЦИЕЙ** (лат. contaminatio «смешение»), и оно не редкость в русской грамматике.

Но **[в некоторых источниках](https://scicenter.online/russkiy-yazyik-scicenter/znaki-prepinaniya-slojnyih-137338.html)**  такие структуры названы **некорректными**.

Answer (score 4):

Добавлю о сказуемом.

*Самый хороший подарок — это **когда ты с душой что-то даришь***.
Сказуемое здесь — целое предложение.

> **3.** Тире ставится перед словами ***это, это есть, значит, это значит, вот,*** присоединяющими сказуемое к подлежащему: <...> *Самая поздняя **осень** — это **когда от морозов рябина сморщится и станет,** как говорят, «сладкой»* (Пришв.) — в роли сказуемого выступает целое предложение.

[**Тире между подлежащим и сказуемым**](http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=91) (справочник Розенталя)